# Posting the data from the 'content' tab of four different rows in sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm in need of some assistance with Ruby on Rails and Sqlite3.

This is what I did four times:

`<%= Bullet.select(:content).order('random()').limit(1).collect { |b| b.content } %>`

But instead of four different random "bullets" it will do four of the same bullets chosen randomly from the list of bullets I have.

I also have tried select * from bullets order by random() limit 4; in sqlite3 (using the program sqliteman) and have also done select * from bullets order by random() limit 1; four times.

Any idea on how I can do this successfully in Ruby on Rails by accessing the database table and using embedded ruby (.erb)?

I'm a bit of a newbie, so I'll need to know where to put what. (e.g. the file I'm displaying the bullet content pulled is show.html.erb, and its controller is students_controller.rb | I am also using sqliteman so I'll need to know if I do anything with that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this now:

```
<% random_bullets = Bullet.all %>
<ul>
  <% random_bullets.shuffle.first(4).each do |r| %>
    <li><%= r.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

This new method will get the `random_bullets` array, shuffle it and get the 4 first bullets.
This way, it would be always different bullets.

Comment: I love the answer, but it gave me (literally) four bullets without the content of those bullets.

Comment: Call the attribute in the end. `random_bullets.sample.any_bullet_attribute`

Comment: Where would I do so?

EDIT: I'm terribly sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: So I put <%= at everything from what you posted, and it's working to some extent.

Comment: <%= 4.times do %>
    <li><%= random_bullets.sample.content %></li>

It's working now but with the above code you helped me with, it shows a random "4" after the bullets. I looked through the code and didn't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind haha. I got it cleared up, thank you so much, I owe you big time!! I took the = off the 4.times do and it worked appropriately. Once again, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I can't vote up until I have 15 reputation, but I will definitely do so as soon as I get there! :)

Comment: The area in which it should be is now a 1-line blank white spot.

EDIT: Would you like to message me on something or e-mail me?

Comment: So I suppose a moderator had removed all of my upvotes for you, because I had gotten you up to 800 or so rep. :(

Comment: It's because of the timing. When someone gets upvoted in a matter of a few minutes the rolled back all the upvotes.